# How to execute a query that joins parts of two existing tables and inserts it into a new table?

Tags: sql

I have a table with surveys and a table with widgets. Between these two tables there should be a third table that connects the two. The following is precisely what I'm looking for.

```
Survey:

survey_id   numeric(18, 0)  Unchecked Primary Key
dashboard_id    numeric(18, 0)  Unchecked Foreign Key
survey_title    nvarchar(250)   Unchecked

Widget:

widget_id   numeric(18, 0)  Unchecked Primary Key
dashboard_id    numeric(18, 0)  Checked Foreign Key
```

The two tables have dashboard_id in common (the primary key of a dashboard table).

**Question:**

How do I join these two tables based on their matching dashboard_id and insert this new table into my third table. And how do I put the two primary keys of the above tables into the new t hird table, which looks like this:

```
Survey_link_widget:

survey_link_widget_id   numeric(18, 0)  Unchecked
survey_id   numeric(18, 0)  Unchecked
widget_id   numeric(18, 0)  Unchecked
data_series_name    nvarchar(250)   Unchecked
data_series_displaytitle    nvarchar(250)   Checked
```

survey_link_widget_id is auto incremented, which will create itself.
survey_id and widget_id should be from the two tables that I intend to join based on dashboard_id

Additionally, would it be hard to add the 4th and 5th column (data_series_name and data_series_displaytitle) to the insert/join query I'm looking for?

If you think I'm handling this 'link table' completely wrong, please tell me! My SQL is really rusty at the moment, so I might just be doing silly things.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of different possibilities, but here is a general idea for you:

```
INSERT INTO Survey_link_widget (survey_id, widget_id)
SELECT
    survey_id,
    widget_id
FROM
    Survey INNER JOIN Widget ON Survey.dashboard_id = Widget.dashboard_id
```

Beyond that, you ask about adding `data_series_name` and `data_series_displaytitle`, and certainly you can do that (just add them to the comma-delimited list in the first line), but if you do, they you'll have to put some data into those fields (i.e., add a 3rd and 4th item to the SELECT clause) -- which can be a field, or it can be static (put something in quotes).